# How do I Display "specific" Data in a Column View using rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In my View I have a table that contains 3 Columns (Product Name, POC, Date). 
I have 3 date values (est_delivery_date, actual_receive_date, actual_delivery_date) and I just need 
1 of them displayed in the "Date" Column based on the following logic:

I have added the following code to my projects_helper.rb:

```
module ProjectsHelper
  def project_date(project)
      if project.actual_delivery_date.present? 
         project.actual_delivery_date
      elsif project.actual_delivery_date.blank? && project.actual_receive_date.present?
         project.actual_receive_date
      else
         project.est_delivery_date
      end
  end
end
```

In the View I added:

```
<td><%= project_date(project) %></td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a helper for this.  Here's a sketch, you should find other helpers already in your `app/helpers` directory.

```
module ProductHelper

  def product_date(product)
    if project.actual_delivery_date.present?
      product.actual_delivery_date
    elsif ...
    ...
  end

end
```

Then, in the view, instead of using the date directly, you'd use `product_date(product)`, and you'll get the right one.

Comment: I am actually new to Rails and this is my first App, so unfortunately I have no other helpers. I went into the Products_helper.rb and added the Sketch you provided, with the elsif and else coded as well. Then in the View I added <%= product_date(product) %> in my column. I get a syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting keyword_end.... Do I need to declare the Helper in the products_controller.rb?

Comment: Sounds like you have a mismatched `end` in the helper, make sure any `if` or `def` or `module` has an `end` paired with it.  Helpers are automatically available to views.

Comment: Thanks Nick. Wow, didn't even realize def and if both needed end.